# conda build ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytest-runner

Tags: python, anaconda

I have my code [here](https://github.com/NEGU93/cvnn). I upload it regularly to both [PIP](https://pypi.org/project/cvnn/) and [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/negu93/cvnn). However, since I added [this line](https://github.com/NEGU93/cvnn/blob/8905fea784dd09d373ff12d0883d64840a25a471/setup.py#L29) to the `setup.py` conda is not compiling.

So PIP works great, as usual, I do `python setup.py sdist` and works like charm. However, when I do `conda build .` it has the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytest-runner
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytest-runner
```

I saw this error all over the web but normally this is for installing and not uploading. Furthermore, the solutions seems to be to just install the library but in my case is already installed:

```
$ conda install -c anaconda pytest-runner
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Full message:

```
$ conda build .
No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.11
WARNING:conda_build.metadata:No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.11
Copying /home/barrachina/Documents/cvnn to /home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/work/
Adding in variants from internal_defaults
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults
Attempting to finalize metadata for cvnn
INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for cvnn
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
BUILD START: ['cvnn-1.0.4-py_0.tar.bz2']
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    _libgcc_mutex:    0.1-conda_forge          conda-forge
    _openmp_mutex:    4.5-1_gnu                conda-forge
    ca-certificates:  2020.12.5-ha878542_0     conda-forge
    certifi:          2020.12.5-py37h89c1867_1 conda-forge
    ld_impl_linux-64: 2.35.1-hea4e1c9_1        conda-forge
    libffi:           3.3-h58526e2_2           conda-forge
    libgcc-ng:        9.3.0-h2828fa1_18        conda-forge
    libgomp:          9.3.0-h2828fa1_18        conda-forge
    libstdcxx-ng:     9.3.0-h6de172a_18        conda-forge
    ncurses:          6.2-h58526e2_4           conda-forge
    openssl:          1.1.1i-h7f98852_0        conda-forge
    pip:              21.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    python:           3.7.9-hffdb5ce_0_cpython conda-forge
    python_abi:       3.7-1_cp37m              conda-forge
    readline:         8.0-he28a2e2_2           conda-forge
    setuptools:       49.6.0-py37h89c1867_3    conda-forge
    sqlite:           3.34.0-h74cdb3f_0        conda-forge
    tk:               8.6.10-h21135ba_1        conda-forge
    wheel:            0.36.2-pyhd3deb0d_0      conda-forge
    xz:               5.2.5-h516909a_1         conda-forge
    zlib:             1.2.11-h516909a_1010     conda-forge

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
source tree in: /home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/work
export PREFIX=/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl
export BUILD_PREFIX=/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/_build_env
export SRC_DIR=/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/work
Using pip 21.0 from $PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
Non-user install because user site-packages disabled
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.org/simple
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-aiaii66z
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-btl00fiq
Initialized build tracking at /tmp/pip-req-tracker-btl00fiq
Created build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-btl00fiq
Entered build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-btl00fiq
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-install-vgiz8uiu
Processing $SRC_DIR
  Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-build-spp5p5g1
  Added file://$SRC_DIR to build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-btl00fiq'
    Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-req-build-spp5p5g1/setup.py) egg_info for package from file://$SRC_DIR
    Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-3kcdcujb
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytest-runner
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytest-runner
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpu1njeuz9', '--quiet', 'pytest-runner']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-req-build-spp5p5g1/setup.py", line 40, in <module>
        'full': ['prettytable', 'matplotlib', 'seaborn', 'plotly', 'tikzplotlib']
      File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 162, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 157, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 702, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 781, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1064, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1076, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 758, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpu1njeuz9', '--quiet', 'pytest-runner']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
WARNING: Discarding file:///home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/work. Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 189, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 178, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 101, in resolve
    req, requested_extras=(),
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 319, in make_requirement_from_install_req
    raise self._build_failures[ireq.link]
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 167, in _make_candidate_from_link
    name=name, version=version,
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 306, in __init__
    version=version,
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 226, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 312, in _prepare_distribution
    self._ireq, parallel_builds=True,
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 457, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 501, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    req, self.req_tracker, self.finder, self.build_isolation,
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 66, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(finder, build_isolation)
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 41, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self.req.prepare_metadata()
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 549, in prepare_metadata
    self.metadata_directory = self._generate_metadata()
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 529, in _generate_metadata
    details=self.name or f"from {self.link}"
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/build/metadata_legacy.py", line 73, in generate_metadata
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info',
  File "$PREFIX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/subprocess.py", line 258, in call_subprocess
    raise InstallationSubprocessError(proc.returncode, command_desc)
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationSubprocessError: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
Removed file://$SRC_DIR from build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-btl00fiq'
Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-btl00fiq'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/bin/conda-build", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 469, in main
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 460, in execute
    verify=args.verify, variants=args.variants)
  File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/api.py", line 209, in build
    notest=notest, need_source_download=need_source_download, variants=variants)
  File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 2344, in build_tree
    notest=notest,
  File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 1492, in build
    cwd=src_dir, stats=build_stats)
  File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 398, in check_call_env
    return _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ('call', *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 378, in _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, _args)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/bin/bash', '-o', 'errexit', '/home/barrachina/anaconda3/conda-bld/cvnn_1611601240565/work/conda_build.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytest-runner` when building with conda a `noarch` package. (Note: when using specific Python versions and arch instead of `noarch`, it worked fine).

After changing my `setup.py` like this:

```py
setup(
    ...
    setup_requires=[],  # instead of: setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],

    ...
)
```

then everything seems to work without the error (and the tests are still being done as part of the conda building).

Answer (score 0):

Got the same kind of a problem. I have installed anaconda and have updated it. Then tried to install NumPy through CMD. But this is the message I got.

```
C:\Users\Rajitha Amarasinghe>conda install numpy
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Then I tried installing conda from pip, this is the message I got. I am not sure whether I have a sufficient case to ask a new question, so I added my experience here.

```
C:\Users\Rajitha Amarasinghe>pip install conda
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement conda (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for conda
```

For your information, I still have the same problem.

Comment: Please adjust your SO search to include topics on starting conda or ask a new question, currently the answer is not relevant. Also - https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#starting-conda

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32097901)